# Simplifying multiple same functions into one

Tags: jquery

new to jquery here. I have a function as below, but I'm pretty sure there's a neater way to shorten things up. How do I simplify this?

```
var checkAttr1 = div.attr('data-featureid-1')
var checkAttr2 = div.attr('data-featureid-2')
var checkAttr3 = div.attr('data-featureid-3')
var checkAttr4 = div.attr('data-featureid-4')
var checkAttr5 = div.attr('data-featureid-5')
var checkAttr6 = div.attr('data-featureid-6')
var checkAttr7 = div.attr('data-featureid-7')
var checkAttr8 = div.attr('data-featureid-8')
var checkAttr9 = div.attr('data-featureid-9')
var checkAttr10 = div.attr('data-featureid-10')

if(checkAttr1){$('.tickee[data-tickid="1"]').css('display','block')}
if(checkAttr2){$('.tickee[data-tickid="2"]').css('display','block')}
if(checkAttr3){$('.tickee[data-tickid="3"]').css('display','block')}
if(checkAttr4){$('.tickee[data-tickid="4"]').css('display','block')}
if(checkAttr5){$('.tickee[data-tickid="5"]').css('display','block')}
if(checkAttr6){$('.tickee[data-tickid="6"]').css('display','block')}
if(checkAttr7){$('.tickee[data-tickid="7"]').css('display','block')}
if(checkAttr8){$('.tickee[data-tickid="8"]').css('display','block')}
if(checkAttr9){$('.tickee[data-tickid="9"]').css('display','block')}
if(checkAttr10){$('.tickee[data-tickid="10"]').css('display','block')}
```

Comment: You can simply loop from 1 to 10. Or show us the HTML.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

set a class to all the div then use `.each()` function

```
$.each('classname', function(){
    $(this).css('display', 'block')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop. Try this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    setDisplay(div, i);
}

function setDisplay(div, i) {
    if (div.attr('data-featureid-' + i)
        $('.tickee[data-tickid="' + i + '"]').css('display', 'block');
}
```